# Web app not working on Chromium in Chrome OS

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-chrome, angularjs, google-chrome-os

I'm working on a web app for note-taking called VideoNot.es (http://videonot.es). This app is build with AngularJS and webapp2 and hosted on the Google App Engine.

My app is working fine on Chrome for the major OS (Windows, Mac, Linux) but some users have started to report issues with Chrome OS (mainly teachers with GAFE accounts).

I've decided to run it in Virtualbox and there is effectively an issue.

The app never receives answer send over the Google Channel API (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview) while the backend is logging that it sent it. I had received reports before we moved to it so it is not really link to it.

I really don't understand what is wrong here.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a bug in the Javascript, you'd want to file it on the issue tracker.  I haven't noticed much progress on Channel API bugs, so I wouldn't expect much though.

I'd recommend working around it by polling, or another solution, like Node.js hosted elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So it is a known issue? Nothing is logged in the Chromium console. Ho Node.JS could solve it, can't see the point there. 
Basically it was not working either without the Channel API so I guess there is something wrong somewhere else.

Comment: I don't know of an issue, I'm just taking your word that you've debugged it and isolated it to the Channel API javascript.  Node.js is frequently used for long polling implementations similar to Channel API's functionality.  Personally, I've been using the Channel API, but have been backing it up with polling.  I don't find it reliable.

You may also be dealing with a router or something that disconnects the TCP socket that the Channel API is using.  You should verify that you aren't getting any onError events with the Channel API javascript, or that you're handling them properly.

Comment: Ok! Good to know, thanks for pointing it out. I've put breakpoints in the onError, onMessage events but nothing fired it up.
I will try to find alternatives since people are experiencing the same kind of issues on regular Chrome (Windows, OSX, Linux edition).

Comment: I've just rollbacked to a version without the Channel API and things are now working as expected.
I don't really know what is wrong with Chrome and Chrome OS on some machines (since it is working on mine) but this particular issue was effectively linked to this API. Thanks a lot for your help!